# Highcharts : Disable top spacing from column graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I get a problem with highchart, I want my graph to take the entire space according, but there is alway a space between the datas and the top of my div.

Here if my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/w2bz5/35/

Here is my javascript code :

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column',
                backgroundColor: '#3d3d3d',
                margin: [0, 0, 0, 0],
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
            },
            title: {
                text: null,
                margin: 0,
                floating: true,
                verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                x: 0,
                y: 0
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: null,
                    margin: 0
                },
                labels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                lineWidth: 0,
                minorGridLineWidth: 0,
                lineColor: 'transparent',
                minorTickLength: 0,
                tickLength: 0
            },
            tooltip: {
                enabled: false
            },
            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                labels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                lineWidth: 0,
                minorGridLineWidth: 0,
                lineColor: 'transparent',
                minorTickLength: 0,
                tickLength: 0
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                data: [1298],
                color: '#00FF00',
                borderColor: null
            }, {
                data:[4302],
                color: '#FF0000',
                borderColor: null
            }]
        });
    });
```

Thanks in advance !

Snite

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to set **stacking** to **percent**, rather than *normal*.

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
       stacking: 'percent',
       dataLabels: {
          enabled: false
       }
    }
},
```

Documentation: [High Charts Documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.stacking)

*Normal* stacking assumes there will be various values for each column, which would mean you would have different sizes of columns--that's why it leaves the space at the top. Setting it to percent would mean every column would be the same height regardless of the values it contains.

On a side note, the **export button** is going to be in the way of the graph if you intend on keeping them this small. You can remove it by adding this to your list of options.

```
exporting: {
    enabled: false  
}
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/w2bz5/36/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also set [maxPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.maxPadding) nad [spacingTop](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.spacingTop) as 0, then set `max` value.

http://jsfiddle.net/sbochan/w2bz5/37/